# Panel Data for the membership of GATT/WTO

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

I need a panel data for the membership of GATT and WTO for all countries in the world. Do you know where to download such a file?

Answer (score 2):

[Mario Larch's Regional Trade Agreements Database](http://www.ewf.uni-bayreuth.de/en/research/RTA-data/index.html)

This database includes all multilateral and bilateral trade agreements as notified to the World Trade Organization for the last 66 years from 1950 to 2015. There is a total of 468 agreements in the dataset that are differentiated along five different categories. Additionally there are variables indicating whether countries were founding members or joined later.